# Car computer in python / GPS tracking

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi

I have an old car that I use for long distance driving and have coded an onboard computer based on a Raspberry Pi 3 and a few other modules. It's my first project in Python and while I've already gotten some help, I now have a version of my project which works quite well.

I use a FONA 808 from Adafruit as the cellular modem (via serial), the Sparkfun NEO-M9N as a GPS sensor (i2c), an OLED display (i2c) and a small temperature sensor via 1-wire.
Here is a link to a picture of the computer in action, just so you have a better picture of it: https://www.instagram.com/p/CJO9HnNneg2/

I'd appreciate getting some optimization tips to make it run smoothly. I'm especially unsure on how I've used threading and if I'm being really efficient with the GPS and the logging etc... Thanks!

(also, if the question is missing some information, don't downvote, comment and I'll correct it)

```
import os
from threading import Thread
import glob
import serial
import subprocess
import urllib
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse
import array
import requests
from time import sleep
from luma.core.interface.serial import i2c
from luma.core.render import canvas
from luma.oled.device import sh1106
from PIL import ImageFont, Image, ImageDraw
import time
import board
import busio
import subprocess
import pymysql
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from haversine import haversine, Unit
import csv
import pandas
import datetime
import pathlib
import json
import smbus
import logging
import pynmea2

################## config display ##################
device = sh1106(i2c(port=1, address=0x3c), rotate=0)
device.clear()
global pending_redraw
pending_redraw = False

### setup different fonts
FA_solid = ImageFont.truetype('/home/pi/Desktop/fonts/fa-solid-900.ttf', 12)
FA_solid_largest = ImageFont.truetype('/home/pi/Desktop/fonts/fa-solid-900.ttf', 40)
text_largest = ImageFont.truetype('/home/pi/Desktop/fonts/digital-7.ttf', 58)
text_medium = ImageFont.truetype('/home/pi/Desktop/fonts/digital-7.ttf', 24)
text_small = ImageFont.truetype('/home/pi/Desktop/fonts/digital-7.ttf', 18)
 
### Initialize drawing zone (aka entire screen)
output = Image.new("1", (128,64))
add_to_image = ImageDraw.Draw(output)

### coordinates always: padding-left, padding-top. the first pair of zone is always = start

# temp_ext
temp_zone = [(14,44), (36,64)]
temp_start = (14,44)
temp_icon_zone = [(0,48), (15,64)]
temp_icon_start = (3,48)

# alti
alti_zone = [(14,22), (69,40)]
alti_start = (14,22)
alti_icon_zone = [(0,24), (15,40)]
alti_icon_start = (0,26)

# distance
dist_zone = [(14,0), (69,21)]
dist_start = (14,0)
dist_icon_zone = [(0,4), (15,21)]
dist_icon_start = (0,4)

# speed
speed_zone = [(66,0), (128,45)]
speed_start = (66,0)

# GPRS status
gprs_zone = [(114,46), (128,64)]
gprs_start = (114,50)

# GPS status, incl. GPS startup icon
status_icon_zone = [(70,50), (88,64)]
status_icon_start = (70,50)
status_zone = [(86,46), (113,64)]
status_start_text = (86,46)
status_start = (86,50)

# usage
#add_to_image.rectangle(speed_zone, fill="black", outline = "black")
#add_to_image.text(speed_start, "\uf00c", font=FA_solid, fill="white")
#device.display(output)




################## upload data from GPS folder via FONA to MySQL ##################
def fix_nulls(s):
    for line in s:
        yield line.replace('\0','')
def upload_data():
    while True:
        sleep(20)
        current_dir = "/home/pi/Desktop/data/gps"
        archive_dir = "/home/pi/Desktop/data/gps/archive"
        path, dirs, files = next(os.walk(current_dir))
        file_count = len(files)
        if file_count < 2:
            print("Not enough GPS.csv files found so it's probably in use now or doesn't exist")
            return
        list_of_files = glob.glob(current_dir+"/*.csv")
        oldest_file = min(list_of_files, key=os.path.getctime)
        oldest_file_name = os.path.basename(oldest_file)
        
        try:
            add_to_image.rectangle(gprs_zone, fill="black", outline = "black")
            add_to_image.text(gprs_start, "\uf0c2", font=FA_solid, fill="white")
            global pending_redraw
            pending_redraw = True
            print("Opening remote db")
            
            openPPPD()
            print("Opening remote db: done")
            
            db = pymysql.connect("XXX","XXX","XXX","XXX" )
            cursor = db.cursor()
            csv_data = csv.reader(fix_nulls(open(oldest_file)))
            next(csv_data)
            for row in csv_data:
                if row:
                    cursor.execute('INSERT INTO gps_data_2 (gps_time, gps_lat, gps_long, gps_speed) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)',row)
            print("Commiting to db")
            db.commit()
            cursor.close()
            
            closePPPD()
            
            print("Successfully commited to db")
            add_to_image.rectangle(gprs_zone, fill="black", outline = "black")
            add_to_image.text(gprs_start, "\uf058", font=FA_solid, fill="white")
            pending_redraw = True
            

            os.rename(current_dir+"/"+oldest_file_name, archive_dir+"/archive_"+oldest_file_name)        
            sleep(60)
            add_to_image.rectangle(gprs_zone, fill="black", outline = "black")
            
        except Exception as e:
            print("Database error:", e)        
            sleep(60)
            add_to_image.rectangle(gprs_zone, fill="black", outline = "black")
            return
        
        sleep(300)




################## config and start GPS ##################
BUS = None
address = 0x42
gpsReadInterval = 1
reading_nr = 1
reading_nr_upload = 1
reading_nr_upload_nbrowsinlog = 0
total_km = 0
prev_lat = 0
prev_long = 0

def connectBus():
    global BUS
    BUS = smbus.SMBus(1)

def parseResponse(gpsLine):
    gpsChars = ''.join(chr(c) for c in gpsLine)
    local_pending_redraw = False
    
    if "$GNGGA" in gpsChars:
        if ",1," not in gpsChars:
            print("Looking for fix... (GGA)")
            add_to_image.rectangle(status_icon_zone, fill="black", outline = "black")
            add_to_image.rectangle(status_zone, fill="black", outline = "black")
            add_to_image.text(status_icon_start, "\uf124", font=FA_solid, fill="white")
            add_to_image.text(status_start, "\uf128", font=FA_solid, fill="white")
            local_pending_redraw = True
            return False
        try:
            nmea = pynmea2.parse(gpsChars, check=True)
            #print("GGA:", '%.6f'%(nmea.latitude), ",",'%.6f'%(nmea.longitude), ", sats:", nmea.num_sats, ", alt:", nmea.altitude) # GGA
            if "0.0" in str(nmea.latitude):
                return False
            if "0.0" in str(nmea.longitude):
                return False
            
            ## show fix + nb satellites
            #num_sats = str(nmea.num_sats)
            #num_sats = num_sats.lstrip("0")
            #add_to_image.rectangle(status_icon_zone, fill="black", outline = "black")
            #add_to_image.rectangle(status_zone, fill="black", outline = "black")
            #add_to_image.text(status_icon_start, "\uf124", font=FA_solid, fill="white")
            #add_to_image.text(status_start_text, num_sats, font=text_medium, fill="white")
            
            ## update altitude
            add_to_image.text(alti_icon_start, "\uf077", font=FA_solid, fill="white")
            add_to_image.rectangle(alti_zone, fill="black", outline = "black")
            add_to_image.text(alti_start, str('%.0f'%(nmea.altitude)), font=text_medium, fill="white")
            
            ## update total distance
            global reading_nr
            global total_km
            global prev_lat
            global prev_long
            dist = 0
            if reading_nr != 1:
                dist = haversine(((float(prev_lat)), (float(prev_long))), ((float(nmea.latitude)), (float(nmea.longitude))))
                total_km = total_km+dist
                add_to_image.text(dist_icon_start, "\uf1b9", font=FA_solid, fill="white")
                add_to_image.rectangle(dist_zone, fill="black", outline = "black")
                add_to_image.text(dist_start, "%0.1f" % total_km, font=text_medium, fill="white")
            prev_lat = nmea.latitude
            prev_long = nmea.longitude
            
            local_pending_redraw = True
            reading_nr +=1
            
        except Exception as e:
            print("GGA parse error:", e)
            add_to_image.rectangle(status_zone, fill="black", outline = "black")
            local_pending_redraw = True
            pass
        
    if "$GNRMC" in gpsChars:
        if ",A," not in gpsChars: # 1 for GGA, A for RMC
            print("Looking for fix... (RMC)")
            add_to_image.rectangle(status_icon_zone, fill="black", outline = "black")
            add_to_image.rectangle(status_zone, fill="black", outline = "black")
            add_to_image.text(status_icon_start, "\uf124", font=FA_solid, fill="white")
            add_to_image.text(status_start, "\uf128", font=FA_solid, fill="white")
            local_pending_redraw = True
            return False
        try:
            nmea = pynmea2.parse(gpsChars, check=True)
            if "0.0" in str(nmea.latitude):
                return False
            if "0.0" in str(nmea.longitude):
                return False
            add_to_image.rectangle(status_zone, fill="black", outline = "black")
            
            ## update speed
            add_to_image.rectangle(speed_zone, fill="black", outline = "black")
            add_to_image.text(speed_start, str('%.0f'%(nmea.spd_over_grnd*1.852)), font=text_largest, fill="white")
            local_pending_redraw = True
            
            ## log every 5th GPS coordinate in CSV file
            global reading_nr_upload
            global reading_nr_upload_nbrowsinlog
            #print(reading_nr_upload)
            if reading_nr_upload % 5 == 0:
                t = datetime.datetime.combine(nmea.datestamp, nmea.timestamp).strftime("%s")
                d = datetime.datetime.combine(nmea.datestamp, nmea.timestamp).strftime("%Y%m%d%H")
                filename = '/home/pi/Desktop/data/gps/gps_' + d + '.csv'
                with open(filename, 'a', newline='') as csvfile:
                    gps_writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
                    gps_writer.writerow([t, nmea.latitude, nmea.longitude, nmea.spd_over_grnd*1.852])
                reading_nr_upload_nbrowsinlog +=1
                print("Added to log. Total in Log from this session is", reading_nr_upload_nbrowsinlog)
                add_to_image.rectangle(status_icon_zone, fill="black", outline = "black")
                add_to_image.rectangle(status_zone, fill="black", outline = "black")
                add_to_image.text(status_icon_start, "\uf124", font=FA_solid, fill="white")
                add_to_image.text(status_start, "\uf56f", font=FA_solid, fill="white")
            reading_nr_upload +=1
            
            #print("RMC: speed is", nmea.spd_over_grnd*1.852) # RMC
            #print("RMC nmea.longitude:", nmea.longitude)
            
        except Exception as e:
            print("RMC parse error:", e)
            add_to_image.rectangle(status_zone, fill="black", outline = "black")
            local_pending_redraw = True
            pass
        
    if local_pending_redraw == True:
        global pending_redraw
        pending_redraw = True

def readGPS(gpsReadInterval=1):
    c = None
    response = []
    try:
        while True: # Newline, or bad char.
            global BUS
            c = BUS.read_byte(address)
            if c == 255:
                return False
            elif c == 10:
                break
            else:
                response.append(c)
        parseResponse(response)
    except IOError:
        time.sleep(0.5)
        connectBus()

connectBus()
def updateGPS(gpsReadInterval=1):
    while True:
        readGPS()
        #sleep(gpsReadInterval)





################## config external thermometer ##################
def update_temp_ext(temp_signature='t=', update_interval=60):
    sleep(10)
    add_to_image.text(temp_icon_start, "\uf2c9", font=FA_solid, fill="white")
    while True:
        f = open('/sys/bus/w1/devices/28-012032ffbd96/w1_slave', 'r')
        lines = f.readlines()
        f.close()
        equals_pos = lines[1].find(temp_signature)
        if equals_pos != -1:
            temp_string = lines[1][equals_pos+2:]
            temp_c = round(float(temp_string) / 1000.0)
            add_to_image.rectangle(temp_zone, fill="black", outline = "black")
            add_to_image.text(temp_start, str(temp_c), font=text_medium, fill="white")
            global pending_redraw
            pending_redraw = True
            
            #filename = 'data/temp_ext/tempext_' + datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d") + '.csv'
            #with open(filename, 'a', newline='') as csvfile:
            #    temp_ext_writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
            #    temp_ext_writer.writerow([str(temp_c)])
            
            time.sleep(update_interval)
            
            
            
    

################## update display ##################
def update_display():
    while True:
        # there is a potential race condition here, not critical
        global pending_redraw
        if pending_redraw:
            pending_redraw = False
            device.display(output)
        time.sleep(0.1)
            
            

################## start cellular connection ##################          
def openPPPD():
    print("Opening PPPD")
    
    subprocess.call("sudo pon fona", shell=True)
    print("FONA on")
    
    add_to_image.rectangle(gprs_zone, fill="black", outline = "black")
    add_to_image.text(gprs_start, "\uf0c2", font=FA_solid, fill="white")
    global pending_redraw
    pending_redraw = True
    
    sleep(20)
    try:
        add_to_image.rectangle(gprs_zone, fill="black", outline = "black")
        add_to_image.text(gprs_start, "\uf0c2", font=FA_solid, fill="white")
        pending_redraw = True
        urllib.request.urlopen('http://google.com')
        print("Connection is on")
        add_to_image.rectangle(gprs_zone, fill="black", outline = "black")
        add_to_image.text(gprs_start, "\uf382", font=FA_solid, fill="white")
        pending_redraw = True
        return True
    except:
        print("No connection")
        add_to_image.rectangle(gprs_zone, fill="black", outline = "black")
        add_to_image.text(gprs_start, "\uf127", font=FA_solid, fill="white")
        pending_redraw = True
        sleep(5)
        return False

# Stop PPPD
def closePPPD():
    print("turning off PPPD")
    subprocess.call("sudo poff fona", shell=True)
    print("turned off")
    return True


            
            
            
            
            
            
            
            
################## threading and program execution ##################
if __name__ == '__main__':
    temp_ext_thread = Thread(target = update_temp_ext)
    display_thread = Thread(target=update_display)
    gps_thread = Thread(target = updateGPS)
    data_thread = Thread(target = upload_data)
    
    display_thread.start() 
    gps_thread.start()
    data_thread.start()
    temp_ext_thread.start()
    
    display_thread.join()
```

Comment: Welcome to the Code Review Community where we review working code and provide suggestions for how to improve that code. The question is fairly good, but it is border line on working code. What makes it questionable is `but is not super super reliable.`. This is why I haven't voted it up.

Comment: @pacmaninbw thx for your feedback! I meant to say something like "it works, but I wouldn't trust it with my life". It's working at the moment, I believe the only hiccups are when there's a loose contact on my breadboard - I have ordered a PCB to remedy that

Comment: According to some people on this site, Duct tape or Duck tape fixes everything including breadboards.

Comment: While this isn't really about the code, I'm a little concerned about you directly connecting to a remote MySQL server, since that tends to be pretty insecure (your credentials are probably broadcasted to the nearest cell tower in plaintext unless you've set up TLS). I would definitely recommend using a HTTPS POST request instead, along with a PHP script on the server to commit the information to the DB upon receiving said request, possibly also with some authentication, even if HTTP basic auth.

Comment: Don't use `open` ... that might leak file descriptors, which are _rare earth materials_; You might run out.

Comment: @TR_SLimey I actually had that first, POSTing to a server with PHP handling the rest but have run into issues on how to add hundreds of lines at once and thus found adding directly into MySQL easier. Happy for suggestions on how to do it server-side tho

Comment: @DamienBourdonneau Assuming you have full access to your server (as opposed to it being a web host for instance), you could even simply write a Python server, and send the data along a socket using JSON or pickle, which should work just fine. Security-wise, you could just encrypt your traffic with AES using a pre-shared key since this is a project for you exclusively I assume. That would provide authentication also. If it is a webhost and you have to use PHP, you could still format the data as JSON and submit it as the POST body. The only issue with that I can think of is POST body size limit.

Comment: @TR_SLimey sadly, it is a shared host... I'll look into limitations of POST body size and try to think of something. The thing is that since it is mounted in a car, it has to cope with power being cut abruptly at random, which is why I like the approach of preparing then committing. I'm still struggling with Python, dont want to get into making my own servers on top of that :D

Comment: @DamienBourdonneau I see. With the prepare/commit issue, it should be fine since if it's formatted as JSON, the server needs the whole message to start working on it, so there won't be any malformed data, but you could also include a checksum to be sure. As for POST body size, it should be configurable on the server, assuming your host lets you do that. You may want to contact their support and ask, but it should be pretty big by default anyway. Good luck though if you do decide to try it! :)

Comment: I've posted a new question with the updated code: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/254555/car-computer-in-python-gps-tracking-version-2

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There's A LOT going on in your code but I'll try to give you some hints and some suggestions regarding the overall structure/workflow of the code.

- you have really abused the use of `global`s in your code. Some of them don't even make sense. I'd suggest you try and understand what the use of it is and stop using it unless really needed. For example, the use of `global` keyword outside a function has no effect (e.g. `pending_redraw`).
- for setting your fonts, you could easily create a function and a `dataclass` to stick to the DRY principle:

```py
FONTS_BASEDIR = '/home/pi/Desktop/fonts/'


def setup_font(font_filename, value):
    return ImageFont.truetype(
        os.path.join(FONTS_BASEDIR, font_filename),
        value
    )


@dataclass
class Fonts:
    fa_solid = setup_font('fa-solid-900.ttf', 12)
    fa_solid_largest = setup_font('fa-solid-900.ttf', 40)
    text_largest = setup_font('digital-7.ttf', 58)
    text_medium = setup_font('fa-solid-900.ttf', 24)
    text_small = setup_font('fa-solid-900.ttf', 18)
```

- remove the unused imports and try not to duplicate them.
- try to be as clear/accurate as possible in your comments. If I were to believe this: `coordinates always: padding-left, padding-top. the first pair of zone is always = start` which doesn't seem to be the case for `temp_icon_zone` and `temp_icon_start` (`(0, 48)` != `(3, 48)`).
- you have a lot of constants which look more like configuration variables. I'd suggest you create a config file to have easier access to all of these. Config variables should also be named using the `UPPER_CASE` notation. (e.g. `temp_zone` would be `TEMP_ZONE = [(14, 44), (36, 64)]` and `temp_start` would become: `TEMP_START = TEMP_ZONE[0]`)
- try using `os.path.join()` instead of `current_dir + "/" + oldest_file_name, archive_dir + "/archive_" + oldest_file_name` when joining together pieces of a path. (see my example from `setup_font` function)
- you misspelled *committed* and *committing*
- here: `db = pymysql.connect("XXX", "XXX", "XXX", "XXX")` it looks like you're using clear-text credentials. **That's bad practice** and I'd suggest you stop doing that! There are multiple other ways of importing your credentials, one of which would be setting the password as an ENV Variable.
- this:

```py
if "0.0" in str(nmea.latitude):
    return False
if "0.0" in str(nmea.longitude):
    return False
```

can be rewritten as this:

```py
if "0.0" in str(nmea.latitude) or "0.0" in str(nmea.longitude):
    return False
```

or even better:

```py
return "0.0" not in str(nmea.latitude) or "0.0" not in str(nmea.longitude)
```

- here:

```py
f = open('/sys/bus/w1/devices/28-012032ffbd96/w1_slave', 'r')
lines = f.readlines()
f.close()
equals_pos = lines[1].find(temp_signature)
```

you only seem to use whatever it's on the second line of that file, so why keep the whole file into memory? Try to break after you reached that very line:

```py
with open('/sys/bus/w1/devices/28-012032ffbd96/w1_slave') as f:
    for i, line in enumerate(f):
        if i == 1:
            equals_pos = line.find(...)
            break
```

Comment: that's great, thanks for the feedback! I'll look into your comments (which all make sense from a first read), implement them and edit/comment when confused or successful!
Also, I'm not not sure about threading at the end and on which thread I join - does that look right to you?

Comment: Please don’t edit your code but rather ask a follow-up question instead with the new code to be reviewed. Also, it’s worth allowing 1-2 days until accepting an answer since there might be valuable input still coming from other reviewers

Comment: `return "0.0" not in str(nmea.latitude) or "0.0" not in str(nmea.longitude)` does not have the same behavior as the first rewrite because it changes a conditional return to an unconditional return

Comment: @GrajdeanuAlex I'm implementing everything atm but I have a few questions: following your advice, I now have an .ini file with different config variables etc. Is that a safe(r) place to store the mysql info? Also, regarding ```TEMP_ZONE = [(14, 44), (36, 64)]```: I have added that to my ini file too but it seems that when I try to use it, it is not seen as a tuple but just some random string and thus the coordinates are not read correctly. Got any tips on that? Have been unsuccessful so far. The rest I've implemented as far as possible!

Comment: "_Is that a safe(r) place to store the mysql info?_" -> not quite / it depends. It's usually a common practice to have a `.env` file where you can store these kind of things. You also have to make sure you don't add this `.env` file to git. The parsed configuration (from this env file) is used as a basis for adding environment variables. If you want to keep the data structures and use them in your code, you can use, at any point, any other data type format like a yaml file / json file or even a `config.py`.

Comment: I've posted a new question with the updated code: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/254555/car-computer-in-python-gps-tracking-version-2

Answer (score 6):

Other minor points:

### Generators

Your generator -

```
for line in s:
    yield line.replace('\0','')
```

can be simplified to

```
return (line.replace('\0', '') for line in s)
```

To see what the difference is, we borrow from some techniques in a [different answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39427083/313768):

```
>>> def f():
...     for c in 'a b':
...         yield c.replace(' ', '')

>>> def g():
...     return (c.replace(' ', '') for c in 'a b')

>>> from inspect import isgeneratorfunction
>>> from dis import dis

>>> isgeneratorfunction(f)
True
>>> isgeneratorfunction(g)
False

>>> dis(f)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 ('a b')
              2 GET_ITER
        >>    4 FOR_ITER                18 (to 24)
              6 STORE_FAST               0 (c)

  3           8 LOAD_FAST                0 (c)
             10 LOAD_METHOD              0 (replace)
             12 LOAD_CONST               2 (' ')
             14 LOAD_CONST               3 ('')
             16 CALL_METHOD              2
             18 YIELD_VALUE
             20 POP_TOP
             22 JUMP_ABSOLUTE            4
        >>   24 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             26 RETURN_VALUE


>>> dis(g)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (<code object <genexpr> at 0x00000236289E7F50, file "<stdin>", line 2>)
              2 LOAD_CONST               2 ('g.<locals>.<genexpr>')
              4 MAKE_FUNCTION            0
              6 LOAD_CONST               3 ('a b')
              8 GET_ITER
             10 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             12 RETURN_VALUE

Disassembly of <code object <genexpr> at 0x00000236289E7F50, file "<stdin>", line 2>:
  2           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (.0)
        >>    2 FOR_ITER                18 (to 22)
              4 STORE_FAST               1 (c)
              6 LOAD_FAST                1 (c)
              8 LOAD_METHOD              0 (replace)
             10 LOAD_CONST               0 (' ')
             12 LOAD_CONST               1 ('')
             14 CALL_METHOD              2
             16 YIELD_VALUE
             18 POP_TOP
             20 JUMP_ABSOLUTE            2
        >>   22 LOAD_CONST               2 (None)
             24 RETURN_VALUE
```

This demonstrates that writing a *generator function* does not produce equivalent bytecode to writing a *function that returns a generator*. The generator function produces bytecode that is shorter, but the generator-returning function has code that's more terse; so in the end it's somewhat of a wash.

### Paths

It's not a good idea to bake `/home/pi` into your data directory paths. This should be configurable, and/or auto-discovered based on the location of the source. Beyond that, storing your application in a subdirectory of a login user's desktop directory is not a good idea. Do some research on the standard Unix directory layout, which would see your fonts in `/usr/share/my_app`, your application in `/usr/bin`, etc.

Comment: How is converting from a generator to a generator expression any simpler? I don't see how moving the for loop from the line above to behind the expression could be called "simplified" when all you've done is rearrange the code.

Comment: @Peilonrayz I don't understand your comment. Knowing how the interpreter differentiates between these two styles is educational.

Comment: My original comment was actually just wrong, due to a typo in the example function. The `yield` style produces simpler bytecode, but the `return` style requires fewer lines of code. In the end it's a judgement call based on context.

Comment: @Reinderien is `yield from` best of both worlds?

Comment: @GavinS.Yancey It's a stylistic choice, and if performance matters profiling should be done before a decision is made.

Comment: @Reinderien I've tried to take up your feedback on paths but have run in an issue: the script is executed at start via ```systemctl``` and this seems to mess with ```os.getcwd()```. Any suggestion on the auto-discovery part? Can't really figure it out. It works fine when I launch it myself but not on autostart

Comment: Autodiscovery isn't strictly necessary if you choose sane paths for your data. You can omit `getcwd` and hard-code a base path for your fonts like `/usr/share/carcomp/fonts`.

Comment: I've posted a new question with the updated code: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/254555/car-computer-in-python-gps-tracking-version-2